# Division operator in PHP

Tags: php, types, division

I accidentally do a division operator in PHP like this:

```
$a = 012; //or 0012 or even 00012
echo $a/4;
echo gettype($a/4);
```

I got output is: `2.5 double`. //I don't know why output is `2.5`.

I tried again:

```
$a=12;
echo $a/4;
echo gettype($a/4);
```

This will output `3 Integer`.

I have read documentation in `https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php` but still cannot understand this.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A value that stars with zero is octal. So `012` in octal is `10` in decimal. 10 divided 4 is 2.5.

Comment: As I understand if `012` is octal, it will be "auto correct" from octal to decimal?

Comment: No. There's no need to change it's data type because it is already numerical.

Comment: How can it know `012` is octal and `4` is decimal? I tried to change division operator into this:
`$a=012; $b=04; echo $a/$b, echo gettype($a/$b)`
I still get `2.5 double`.
I used caculator in windows, change mode to Oct (stand for octal) and do a division operator `12 / 4`, result is `2`.
I am still confusing about this.

Comment: The leading zero tells PHP the number is octal. And you get the same result because 04 in octal is 4 in decimal. You're doing the same math.

Comment: Yes, i am not confuse anymore. I need to learn about Octal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to clean the value of $a before you use it.

```
$a = ltrim($a, '0');
```

This will remove all preceding 0s and mean that `012 => 12` and not `10` when you cast it to an int

e.g.

```
$a = 0012;
$a = ltrim($a, '0');
echo $a/4;
echo gettype($a/4);
```

Comment: [That's not the right way to do it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php)

Comment: I know that's not the way to convert an oct to a dec, but the question felt like it was bad user data, so someone posted a value of 012 instead of 12 in a form. They mean 12, but the extra 0 forces PHP into oct mode.